# Intellij error 'object update_eori is not a member of package views.html'

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, automation

I am getting the below error while compiling my scala project-

```
object update_eori is not a member of package views.html
import views.html.update_eori
```

This is the package that I am using -

```
import views.html.update_eori
```

What could be possibly going wrong here?

P.S. I am completely new to coding

I tried to run the command sbt clean and then tried to compile again but same error persists.

Comment: It's possible that one of necessary dependencies is not added in `build.sbt`.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)